# Insert Sales Order using Graph

Tags: acumatica

Hello I am trying to save a sales order by using the SOOrderEntry graph but I believe I am missing something in my fields that stopping it from inserting.

Here is my code to insert the sales order, customer and project I get from using PXSelect earlier in the code

```
   PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry>();
            graph.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearAll);

            PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder order = new PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder();

            graph.Document.Current = order;
            order.OrderType = "SO";
            order = graph.Document.Insert(order);

            order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.Status = "N";

            order.CustomerID = cust.BAccountID;
            order.ProjectID = project.ID;

            graph.Document.Update(order);
            graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry>();         

        PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder Sorder = new PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder();

        Sorder.OrderType = SOOrderTypeConstants.SalesOrder;
        Sorder = graph.Document.Insert(Sorder);

        Sorder.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
        Sorder.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
        Sorder.Hold = false;

        Sorder.CustomerID = cust.BAccountID;
        Sorder.ProjectID = project.ID;

        graph.Document.Update(Sorder);
        graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

If there are errors, Please mention what is it.